# How to select Max Value from database in Textbox

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, textbox

i have simple  table item and a text box textbox1 now i want to show max value in textbox  i am using the command but  code  not work

> item table: CREATE TABLE  TableItem( ItemId      NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
>   ItemName    VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, UnitId NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
>   CategoryId NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, ItemStatus  NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
>   SupplierId      NUMBER(10)NOT NULL );

and item table insert data:

> ```
> INSERT INTO TableItem(ITEMID,ITEMNAME,UNITID,CATEGORYID,ITEMSTATUS,SUPPLIERID)
> VALUES(01,'Product-1',21,10,1,51);
> INSERT INTO TableItem(ITEMID,ITEMNAME,UNITID,CATEGORYID,ITEMSTATUS,SUPPLIERID)
> VALUES(02,'Product-2',22,11,1,52);
> INSERT INTO TableItem(ITEMID,ITEMNAME,UNITID,CATEGORYID,ITEMSTATUS,SUPPLIERID)
> VALUES(03,'Product-3',23,12,1,53);
> INSERT INTO TableItem(ITEMID,ITEMNAME,UNITID,CATEGORYID,ITEMSTATUS,SUPPLIERID)
> VALUES(04,'Product-4',24,14,1,53);
> INSERT INTO TableItem(ITEMID,ITEMNAME,UNITID,CATEGORYID,ITEMSTATUS,SUPPLIERID)
> VALUES(05,'Product-5',21,12,1,53);
> INSERT INTO TableItem(ITEMID,ITEMNAME,UNITID,CATEGORYID,ITEMSTATUS,SUPPLIERID)
> VALUES(06,'Product-5',23,12,1,52);
> ```

**now i need max value of  itemid**

```
con.Open();
try
{
    OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX(ItemId)  FROM TableItem", con);

    textBoxInsert.Text = cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

}
finally
{


}

con.Close();
```

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work. Please remove that empty try catch and let the exception show itself with information about the error.

Comment: i have already try   without try catch

Comment: and what is the result of it? empty text box? exception?

Comment: yes text box empty

Comment: it's required convert ? i do not know

Comment: Do you have records in the table _TableItem_? What is the expected return with the current status of your table?

Comment: table also contain data and SELECT MAX(ItemId)  FROM TableItem; also work well

Comment: And what is the expected value this code should return from the data in the TableItem table?

Comment: i have edit the post  i think i have explain ok

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see any reason in your code to fail with the given context. If you can see the six records using a SELECT on the same table then your code should work as well. Otherwise there is something that is not apparent from your code. Perhaps a wrong database? Just guessing.

Comment: you can give  a example for work well pls

Comment: I can only suggest to split your line that reads the result to:  _object result = cmd4.ExecuteScalar();_ and then do a
_textBoxInsert.Text = (result == null ? "0" : result.ToString());_ If you see 0 then your command doesn't work on the set of data that you have inserted at the start of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a data adapter, it will fetch your SQL in your database based on your connection. After that you will get a table as result, so you just need to add it to your DataTable and get the rows. There is more interesting implementations, but with this code you can see if it everything is working fine, I've implemented a MySQL version like this:

```
DataTable _datatable = new DataTable();
MySQLDataAdapter _adapter = new MySQLDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE", connection)
_adapter.Fill(_datatable);

myTextBox.Text = _datatable.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
```

On your case, you just need to replace MySQLDataAdapter with OracleDataAdapter, from OracleClient

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: try this code but  show  this text  in textbox : **System.Data.DataRow**

Comment: The datatable have some value?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. We took the double result for the number we will get in the database.

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT MAX(ItemId) FROM TableItem", con))
{
    con.Open();
    double result = (Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
    textBoxInsert.Text = result.ToString();
}
```